# Three Monitors with Nvidia GeForce GT 525m and Intel HD Graphics on Del XPS 15Z

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-geforce, dell-xps, intel-graphics

I have a brand new Dell XPS 15Z as a replacement for my workstation and I am trying to plug the two monitors that I had with my old machine. I have been looking online and asking some of my coworkers but everything indicates that this is not possible.

The laptop has two cards, the Nvidia GeForce GT 525m and an integrated Intel HD Graphics, two external display's ports, and HDMI and a mini displayport; is there a way to use both graphics cards at the same time so I connect two external monitors?

Thanks for your comments!

Comment: I am also looking for a definitive answer to this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HM67 doesn't allow both graphics cards to run at the same time. So two monitors is max.

Answer (score 1):

The HDMI and Mini DisplayPort can be used simultaneously to drive TWO external monitors. This setup requires the laptop display be disabled.

An alternative option would be to use the [Matrox TripleHead2Go](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/th2go/)  however I’m not certain the GT 525M supports the required resolution.

Answer (score -1):

xps 15z year 2012
I run at the same time:
minidisplay - external monitor
HDMI - external monitor
And the laptop display
= All at the same time all HD 1080P