# Nvidia quadro 2000M and Intel HD graphics - How many monitors can I use while laptop is open?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, nvidia-quadro, dell-precision

I've got a NVIDIA QUADRO 2000M and an INTEL HD GRAPHICS 3000 card on my Dell Precision laptop.  I'd like to, hopefully, be able to plug in 2 monitors and have my laptop open (so 3 screens total) - is this possible with this build?  Do I have any options for expansion to allow this without replacing the graphics cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm definitely not sure about it, but I'll tell what I think I know. It may help someone.

Integrated HD3000 graphics are shipped with the 2nd generation of Core i* processors and are supposed to support only 2 monitors at once.
But, since you also have the discrete graphic card (QUADRO 2000M), I would expect that one to be able to run at least 1 more monitor on its own. Very likely, at gaming you wouldn't be able to use all 3 screens for game itself, but have something like - 2 screen for gaming and one for other programs etc.

But it all depends on specific configuration, types/numbers of video outputs.

**EDIT:**
I did some more reading up ([Three Monitors with Nvidia GeForce GT 525m and Intel HD Graphics on Del XPS 15Z](https://superuser.com/questions/306642/three-monitors-with-nvidia-geforce-gt-525m-and-intel-hd-graphics-on-del-xps-15z?rq=1)) and now I think it won't work after all, since those 2nd generation Core i5/i7 processors use the HM67 chipset and it won't allow you to run both graphic cards at the same time.

Also, you can check this link: http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-033714.htm

Answer (score 1):

The most monitors you'll get off of an nVidia card is 2.

Comment: With the laptop screen open or closed?

Comment: The card can run two monitors at once.  One external and the laptop monitor or two external monitors.

Answer (score 0):

On Dell Precision M4600 (Windows 7 x64) with Nvidia Quadro 2000M delivered in May 2012 I have been able to run two extra Samsung 191T LCD monitors (19") with the following configuration:

The left monitor of the pair is plugged into the VGA port in the back of the laptop using VGA connector cable that came with the monitor (191T comes with both VGA and DVI cables).

The right monitor of the pair is connected to a DVI cable, which is then connected to a DisplayPort adapter for use in display port on the rear of the *right side* of the laptop.

Be sure both monitors are powered off when making hookups. 191Ts have 1620x1050 resolution; the laptop screen has 1920x1080 resolution.

To get the two monitors running, turn them on, then go to Control Panel > Adjust Screen Resolution > Appearances and Personalization > Display > Screen Resolution. In this window click on Monitor 2 and at "Multiple Displays" select "Extend Desktop to this display" Click Apply, and Save Changes. Go through these same steps for the Monitor 3, and you have three screens running. Does fine for 3D CAD modeling (MicroStation v8i ss2). The software takes care of the differing screen sizes with no input from me.

You have to go back through these steps to disconnect each monitor. The connections will survive hibernation most of the time.